# How do I pull all the records that are group by 2 columns?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to pull back all the records that where BOTH have the same records for itemId and itemTypeId. So this should bring back:

Frank M, Max Terry, John M because they both have the itemId/ItemTypeId as 6/7 and 4/7.

items is:

[image]

[image]

I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
  return returnList
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemId, x.ItemTypeId })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > items.Count - 1)
    .Select(z => z.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

I should be able to group by the item type id and then get all the users that are in the item group id and the item id. So if users have both 4/7 and 6/7 they should show up.

EDIT:

The code below returns the right count and right items, but then it duplicates it.
Example:

[image]

I just want this:

[image]

```
return returnList
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemId, x.ItemTypeId })
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(g=>g)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: What is the significance of `g.Count() > items.Count - 1`? Don't you just want `g.Count() > 1`?

Comment: I updated the main post: mjwills ; John - I tried that and it gets the correct count, but then it will show the same user for all 4 records per say. the g.Count() > items.Count -1 is saying take the items.count (which is a record of itemId and itemTypeId) and minus 1 and if the g.count() is greater than that, then return all records that have that same group by.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs specified **in code** and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: mjwills: So the code that was just posted below somewhat works. I thought I posted enough data, but I guess I did not.

Comment: @mjwills: I updated the post, but I had to add a screenshot. That tool wouldn't copy properly into the post. Hopefully I did it right, but those are my expected results.

Comment: Try adding Distinct() method before ToList(). SelectMany(g=>g).Distinct().ToList().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectMany was the key and grouping by UserId

```
                return returnList.GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId })
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > Items.Count - 1).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Everyone played a part in helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
return returnList
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemId, x.ItemTypeId })
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .SelectMany(g=>g)
                .ToList();
```

---

Edit(for duplicates):

I suppose, that's because for group (x.ItemId, x.ItemTypeId) can be more then one row with same initials. You can use additional grouping or 'distinct'.

```
var userItems = new[] {
            new UserItem(926, 1, "TaylorFrank", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(839, 2, "Jonathan M", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(933, 2, "Jonathan M", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(689, 3, "Max Terry", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(925, 3, "Max Terry", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(932, 4, "Frank M", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(931, 4, "Frank M", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(691, 5, "Stephanie K", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(809, 14, "Kevin McCannon", 4, 7),

            //duplication for group  (x.ItemId, x.ItemTypeId )
            new UserItem(1926, 1, "TaylorFrank", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(1839, 2, "Jonathan M", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(1933, 2, "Jonathan M", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(1689, 3, "Max Terry", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(1925, 3, "Max Terry", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(1932, 4, "Frank M", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(1931, 4, "Frank M", 6, 7),
            new UserItem(1691, 5, "Stephanie K", 4, 7),
            new UserItem(1809, 14, "Kevin McCannon", 4, 7),
        };


        var groupedByItemAndType =
            userItems
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemId, x.ItemTypeId })
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

        var distinctUsersInGroup =
            groupedByItemAndType
            .Select(g => new { g.Key, distinctUsers = g.Select(ui => ui.Initials).Distinct() });

        foreach(var item in distinctUsersInGroup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"group: {item.Key}, {string.Join("; ", item.distinctUsers)}");
        }
```

Comment: This gets the right data now, but doubles it. So if I'm suppose to have 4 records, then it will duplicate them twice for 8.  If I could remove the 4 duplicate records, it would be right. I think.